# Can an owned account be on-curve?

Tags: owner

As the title states, is it possible for an account to be on-curve but still be owned by a different account? I'd assume not, as this would make authority weird since said account also has a private key in that case, but wondering if there is cases where this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible! Just about every SPL token mint account is on-curve. Try running:

```
$ solana-keygen new -o mint.json
$ spl-token create-token mint.json
```

Authority can be weird in some of these cases, but programs should be careful to support all sorts of strange ownership scenarios.

For example, it's possible for a token mint be the owner on token accounts, so the SPL token program allows the keypair holder to sign with the token mint's private key to transfer the tokens, even though the account is a mint.

Comment: Learned something new today! Thanks!